# What's the definition of Package in Julia-Lang?

Tags: julia

I have frequently used Packages in Julia-Lang, there are many articles that describes how to work with them, but I don't know what is the exact definition of that.

EDIT

Following is a general definition from wiki:

> Package (package management system), in which individual files or
>   resources are packed together as a software collection that provides
>   certain functionality as part of a larger system

I would like to know the special points of view toward **Package** that Julia-lang has. e.g. look at this definition from wiki about [Java Package](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_package)

Comment: why not google it? [Software package](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_package)

Comment: In my view  it's **Necessary** but **Insufficient** for a set of related files to become a Julia Package only because they  *provides certain functionality as part of a larger system*

Answer (score 2):

I would say that a Julia package is a module (similar to a namespace in other languages) containing a collection of related functions that provide new functionality for Julia, and that will be useful for other people.

This definition is not unambiguous though. For example, I [suggested recently](https://github.com/JuliaLang/METADATA.jl/pull/3544#issuecomment-143904838) that several image format packages could belong inside a single `ImageFormats` package, but the replies were that there was a good reason (code size and binary dependencies) for certain kinds of formats to be in separate packages.

If you follow the discussion of the pull requests for new packages on [`METADATA.jl`](https://github.com/JuliaLang/METADATA.jl/pulls), you will have a good idea about the community's feeling about what packages should be for / look like. My takeaway from following those discussions is that a more-or-less unified vision is starting to emerge.

Comment: I think as cited here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julia_(programming_language)#Packages, one important thing about Julia Package in that they must be a Git repository.